# Optimizing tail-calls in C#

Tags: c#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I've got a deeply recursive function that should in theory work well even with large inputs. The problem is at the time of writing I forgot that C# doesn't do tail-call optimization very well, if at all, so I get `StackOverflowException`s for any complex-enough input. The basic structure of the method is in two large methods, each calling the other.

```
public object Simplify(object param) {
    if (IsSimple(param))
        return param;
    else
        return Expand(param);
}

private object Expand(object param) {
    return Simplify(ProcessExpansion(param));
}
```

Both `IsSimple` and `ProcessExpansion` have a relatively fixed stack depth - the only problem is the recursion between Simplify and Expand. How would you go about reducing the stack depth here?

I was thinking of returning delegates that would calculate the result, but that seems like overkill - there must be a simpler way. This is my thought of a solution (it isn't very polished because I keep thinking I must be doing something horribly wrong here):

```
public object Simplify(object param) {
    object result = () => SimplifyInternal(param);
    while (result is Func<object>)
        result = ((Func<object>)result)();
    return result;
}

private object SimplifyInternal(object param) {
    if (IsSimple(param))
        return param;
    else
        return Expand(param);
}

private object Expand(object param) {
    return () => SimplifyInternal(ProcessExpansion(param));
}
```

So my two questions are:

1. What is it that feels horribly wrong with this solution?
2. Can you think of a better one?

Comment: Just a point to note, the .NET 4.0 x64 runtime optimizes tail calls while the x86 one doesn't. Totally stupid, I know.

Comment: Why not prog it in F#? I'd rather have the compiler optimize it (language feature) then pray the jitter will figure it out.

Comment: As much as I love F#, I'd rank this comment down if I could. Suggesting that you switch an entire project to F# just because you need tail call optimization at one point isn't very constructive.

Comment: @Brian True, you could port just pieces of your code to F#. Nonetheless, I find it to be a bit of a jerk-move for someone to plug another language while you're busy trying to solve a problem in your own -- especially when it's perfectly possible and practical to do so (there's a formal proof somewhere that you can convert all recursions to loops and vice versa).

Comment: Well, the OP's question was originally about tail call optimization (in C# though), but I dont understand the problem in embracing this multi language/multi paradigm framework we are using here. Stuff always scales/evolves and knowing your options should never affect you negatively...

Comment: I was hoping there's something I missed that allows for tail-call optimizations to happen (even without x64). I guess I'll have to change the function to not work that way.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but assuming we were still into this position (with no tail cal) you could use something like trampolining. http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/09/02/tail-recursion-in-c/

Answer (score 8):

Isn't this just

```
while(!IsSimple(param))
    param = ProcessExpansion(param);
return param;
```

?

Comment: The point being, if A calls B only in tail position, and B calls A only in tail position, then you should be able to do a little massaging to merge the two methods and wrap a while loop around it and get the same semantics.

Comment: It is. The example is greatly simplified though - the functions are complicated enough as it is, and each does something completely different. There's also some polymorphism involved with the different types of values that param can have. I could combine them into a single function theoretically, but it would make them far harder to maintain.

Comment: Indeed.  In that case, one possible avenue is to write those functions in F#.  Another is to use a trampoline (looks like you were trying this).  Yet another would to be to use threads (e.g. when the stack gets high, QueueUserWorkItem and block on a result).  None of these options are exceedingly attractive; use the one you are comfortable with authoring and maintaining.  Also, consider if you can "change the problem" to make the issue go away in the first place.

Comment: +1 Brian is correct. I would either write the function in F# or convert it to a loop, whichever is more maintainable (keeping your coworkers and replacements in mind as well as yourself).